# Binding ListView item itself in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a piece of code like this:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Assets}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here Title is a member of Asset object. How can I bind asset itself?

Comment: `{Binding .}` should be the equivalent of `this` so binding the `BindingContext` itself (the Asset object in this case)

Comment: @maxc900 You want to binding listview self in listview itemtemplate Textcell? Or you just want to use [Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) in ListView?